# How do i update a foreign entity?

Tags: scala, sorm

I can't seem to update the fields within a foreign entity using `.copy(..)` and  `Db.save`. No exception gets thrown at all and the `T with Persisted` that gets returned from the method reflects exactly what I attempted to update. However, when I attempt to retrieve the value using `Db.query` or `Db.fetchById`, only the non-foreign fields are updated. For example:

```
case class Foo (a: String)
case class Bar (b: String, barfoo: Foo)
....
....
val foo1 = Db.save(Foo("Hello"))

val bar1 = Db.save(Bar("World", foo1))

val result = Db.save(bar1.copy(b="Beatiful World", 
        barfoo = bar1.barfoo.copy(a = "Hello My")))

println(result) // Prints: Bar(1,Beatiful World,Foo(1,Hello My))

println(Db.fetchById[Bar](result.id)) // Prints: Bar(1,Beatiful World,Foo(1,Hello))
```

So, as you can see the `barfoo` field was not updated.

Is this the wrong way to approach updating foreign entities ? or perhaps this is a bug?

I'm using SORM v0.3.12 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. You need to explicitly update the inner entity. I.e.:

```
Db.save(bar1.barfoo.copy(a = "Hello My"))
Db.save(bar1.copy(b="Beatiful World"))
```

Actually on one stage of SORM's development the update of inner records was automatic (meaning that your example would have worked as you expected), but it required a dedicated `UPDATE` statement which was redundant in cases when the inner entity didn't change. So the decision was made to make it explicit.

This is still a debatable subject and there is a possibility that future versions will choose a different approach.